# How to fix "SyntaxError: Expected "#", "\n", "\r" or [ \t] but "[" found." which is retrieved by yargs module?

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, bitbucket-pipelines, yargs, toml

I'm currently doing continuous deployment with bitbucket pipelines. I've put in a pipe the "npm test" command because I use mocha to do unit tests on my node project.

When I run "npm test" on my local shell to test my routes, each of them works. But when the temporary server of bitbucket run the command, I retrieve this mistake :

```
stork@1.0.0 test /opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build
> mocha tests/**/*.js
/opt/atlassian/pipelines/agent/build/node_modules/mocha/node_modules/yargs/yargs.js:1163
      else throw err
           ^
SyntaxError: Expected "#", "\n", "\r" or [ \t] but "[" found.
npm ERR! Test failed.  See above for more details.
```

I've recently implemented a config.toml file in my repository to put in my code some variable (like domain, path, etc). Since this moment, the unit tests which are run in the pipleline doesn't work anymore.

Is it an issue of toml parsing ?

this is my toml file :

```
title = "configuration"

[charlie]
domain = "localhost"
path = "/"
port = 3000
```

Any tips should be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

After some researches, I've found the origin of the issue.

My toml file was mentioned in the gitignore file to be not put it in my remote repository.

That's why I had to copie/past the entiere toml content to put it in a single bitbucket environment variable. With this technic, I was sure to have a prod version of the config.toml on my server and a dev version of the config.toml on my machine.

The problem was my BitBucket variable has been formatted on a single line. Indeed, the toml format is line break sensitive. That's why I've used a json instead of a toml and the issue has been fixed.